# Searching all nodes of a binary tree in Java

Tags: java, search, binary-tree

I am trying to write a method to search all nodes of a binary tree for a passed value and return the node when found. I cannot seem to get the logic right to search both sides of the tree. Here is what I have so far.

```
private Node locate(String p, Node famTree)
{  
    if (root == null)//If tree empty return null;
        return null;
    if (famTree.value.equals(p)) //If leaf contains the passed parent value the boolean becomes true.
        return famTree;
    if (famTree.left != null)
        return locate(p,famTree.left);
    else
        return locate(p,famTree.right);

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are only searching the right subtree when there is no left subtree. You also want to search it when the string was not found in the left subtree. This should do it:

```
private Node locate(String p, Node famTree)
{
    Node result = null;
    if (famTree == null)
        return null;
    if (famTree.value.equals(p))
        return famTree;
    if (famTree.left != null)
        result = locate(p,famTree.left);
    if (result == null)
        result = locate(p,famTree.right);
    return result;

}
```

Comment: @TwoMore - I don't just return the result of searching the left subtree whenever it is not `null`. I capture the result of searching the left subtree and search the right subtree if it wasn't found.

Comment: Well but somewhen is your leftsubtree the root and the first if will return null am i right?

Comment: It did work Ted. Thank you. This stumped me all day. I think I was trying to imagine a more complex solution.

Comment: @TwoMore - Um...what? I'm assuming that this is called with `locate("Something", root)`.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, somehow i assumed currentNode is checked for null not root, forget it

Comment: @TedHopp You are right . I have removed my answer and +1 to you.